# Change password timeout on Linux?

Tags: linux, passwords, timeout

If I type in the wrong password at login, then the system forces me to wait for about a second before I can retry. Is there a way to reduce this timeout? Also, is there a global timeout setting for su and sudo or do I have to change those timeouts using a different method?

Comment: For sudo-timeout see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/149731/how-i-can-make-sudo-session-an-hour-and-not-few-minutes-in-ubuntu-10-04/149740#149740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `FAIL_DELAY` line in `/etc/login.defs`. That should affect both login and su. But why would you want to do that ?

Comment: "the system forces me to wait for about a second before I can retry" Methinks the OP wants not to wait for a second to retry.

Comment: The option doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever on Archlinux. Neither do any of the three answers currently on this page. But [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677007/59928) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Checking out /etc/login.defs on Ubuntu 11.10 I see that the config option that b0fh mentions has been moved to the /etc/pam.d/login file as:

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
```

which I changed from 3 sec. to half a second in order to lessen the effect of my bad habit of often getting my password wrong on the first go. (I consider the added risk of a brute-force attack taking one-sixth of the time it would have taken otherwise is a negligible factor)

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you. Incorrect passwords, while unoften, drive me crazy.

Comment: @shurane: I might be mistaken but IIRC I felt like changing this value actually didn´t make any difference in my system at the time. Could you confirm that my advice did change your timeout length?

Comment: @GumminV: it does not have any effect for me on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 2):

For some reason editing the delay in `/etc/pam.d/login` has no effect for my Ubuntu 12.04.

It would be best to have a small but nonzero delay (like half a second); I could not do that, but  I was able to disable the delay by editing `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` from

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

to

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay
```

No reboot required.