# Repeated password request in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, ubuntu-10.10, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can make sudo session an hour and not few minutes in Ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/149731/how-i-can-make-sudo-session-an-hour-and-not-few-minutes-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Ubuntu 10.10 asks password everytime I try to do some administrative task. How can I avoid it ? Uhat I can save password for a session?

Answer (score 1):

It's a (security) feature, not a bug!

`sudo` won't ask you for a time, about 15 minutes should be standard. You can adjust that to a longer value using `visudo`:

```
Defaults      env_resets,timestamp_timeout=-1
```

> timestamp_timeout:
>   Number of minutes that can elapse
>   before sudo will ask
>                          for a passwd again.  The default is 15.  Set this
>   to 0
>                          to always prompt for a password.  If set to a
>   value
>                          less than 0 the user’s timestamp will never expire.
>                          This can be used to allow users to create or
>   delete
>                          their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k
>   respectively.

If you really don't like it: log in as `root` (probably by setting a password first and enabling log on to X11)

Comment: Please don't...if you want to, make the `sudo` session last longer, I'm fine with that, but don't work as `root` by default and especially not with an X-Session on top of it...it's a very effective way to nuke your system in *so many different* ways you can't even imagine. There's a reason why it is always frowned upon in the Unix/Linux world...hell, even Microsoft realized this (a decade too late, but hey, at least they're learning).

Comment: @Bobby: absolutely, just as I said: it's a feature ;-)